# Linear transformations, a general question

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Let a linear transformation $R: U \rightarrow W$, $U, W$ are final-dimensional vector spaces. Let $(u_1, ...,u_n)$,  $(w_1, ... w_m)$ be basis of $U$, $W$ s.t $n > m$. Suppose that for each $ 1\leq j\leq m \space R(u_j) = w_j$. Why or is it necessary that for each $ m+1\leq j\leq n \space \space R(u_j) = 0$? I think the abstraction makes it harder for me to see how it relates to the kernel

Answer (score 1):

You might have heard that given a basis of $U$, a linear transformation $R : U\to W$ is **fully specified** by its action on the basis vectors of $U$.

Any (ordered) choice of $n=\dim U$ vectors $w_1,\ldots,w_n$ in $W$ **uniquely** determines a linear transformation with $R(u_j)=w_j$. And vice versa - given $R$ and a basis of $U$, you have a set of $n$ vectors $R(u_1),\ldots,R(u_n)$ that determines $R$.

In your case, you're given only the first $m$ vectors. As $m<n$ and considering the above, the remaining $(n-m)$ vectors required to specify $R$ **are "free" to be chosen** (from $U$) **in any way you want** - not necessarily as the zero vector.

---

Here's another way to look at it: since you have the bases for both spaces, it might help to write out **the matrix** of $R$.

The condition $R(u_j)=w_j$ for $1\le j \le m$ means exactly that the first $m$ columns of $R$'s matrix consist of $(0,\ldots,0,1,0,\ldots 0)$. For example, for $n=6,m=3$ the matrix looks like this:

$$
\begin{pmatrix}1 & 0 & 0 & w & h & a\\
0 & 1 & 0 & t & e & v\\
0 & 0 & 1 & e & r & :)
\end{pmatrix}
$$

Your condition fixed the lefmost "identity square", but did not say anything about the rest of the matrix. Hence the rest can be filled with any scalars you want, not necessarily zeros.

Comment: I see thank you. However I'm trying to understand if the linear transformation R is given and already defined, can we deduce the rest n-m vectors are all at Ker(R)?

Comment: Not necessarily! There are many possible transformations $R$ with the given property (that $R(u_j)=w_j$ for $1≤j≤m$), and in most of them, the remaining $(n-m)$ vectors $w_j$ ($m<j\le n$) will be non-zero - i.e. the $u_j$s will be *outside* of $\operatorname{Ker} R$.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose that $U$ has basis $u_1,u_2$ and that $W$ has basis $w_1$ and that $R$ is the linear transformation $R(au_1+bu_2)=(a+b)w_1$. Then $R(u_2)\ne 0$.

Comment: And then the u2 has to be zero?

Comment: @X4J The zero vector cannot be part of any basis! It itself makes up for a linearly dependent (singleton) set $\{ 0 \}$.

Answer (score 0):

The [rank-nullity theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rank%E2%80%93nullity_theorem) states that

$$\dim\operatorname{im} (T)+\dim\operatorname{Ker}(T)=\dim V$$

so

$$\dim W+\dim\operatorname{Ker}(R)=\dim V$$

$$\dim\operatorname{Ker}(R)=n-m$$

As $R$ transforms one basis into another, we must have the kernel of $R$ ($R(u_k)=0$ ) with dimension $n-m$, i.e. for $m+1\le k\le n$.

Comment: I agree that $\dim \operatorname{Ker} = n-m$, but how does it follow that $u_k \in  \operatorname{Ker}$ for $m<k\le n$?

Comment: In fact, the answer from @ancient mathematician provides an explicit counterexample.

Comment: @Al.G.; a basis has the property that every point is uniquely defined, which any $R(u_{k+1})\ne0$ fails to satisfy.

Comment: I literally got more confused but still appreciate the help, lol.

Comment: @JMP If you mean that "any point (of $U$) is uniquely expressible as a linear combination of the given basis (agan of $U$)", that's correct, but what does have that to do with $R(u_{k+1})$ being zero or non-zero?

Comment: @Al.G.; if $R(u_{k+1})\ne0$, then it can be written in terms of $w_i$, and therefore back in $U$ there is a non-trivial vector $0$ from the basis, a contradiction.

Comment: @Al.G.; because we would have $R(u_{k+1})=\sum R(u_j) =R(\sum u_j)$ which implies $u_{k+1}=\sum u_j$.

Comment: Oh, I see what you're doing. But your *"which implies ..."* only works if $R$ is injective.